# output concatenated arrays to outlook email?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have two 1D arrays that I'm concatenating...one is a timestamp and the other is the corresponding comment

e.g.:

11/9/2012 11:17:30 AM - Bob Follow up with Jim Smith

11/13/2012 11:17:38 AM - Followed up with LOB for status on request.  Awaiting response.

11/28/2012 11:18:15 AM - Mtg with Bob, agreed need to transfer to ownership to Mary Jones

11/29/2012 11:18:27 AM - Mtng w/ MJ, reaching out to locate file.  Due date of 12/7/12

12/10/2012 11:18:43 AM - Joe email to MJ for status update.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Test_Arrays_Click()
Dim dbs As Database, rst As Recordset, Count As Integer
Dim TimeArray()
Dim CommentArray()
Dim strsql As String
Dim i As Long
Dim TimeCommentArray As Variant


Set dbs = CurrentDb

strsql = "SELECT Timestamp, Comment from Conversation_Log where Item_ID = '" & Me.ID & "'"
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strsql)
Count = 0
     ReDim Preserve TimeArray(0)
     rst.MoveFirst
     Do Until rst.EOF
        TimeArray(Count) = rst![Timestamp]

        ReDim Preserve TimeArray(UBound(TimeArray) + 1)
        Count = Count + 1
        rst.MoveNext
     Loop

     ReDim Preserve TimeArray(UBound(TimeArray) - 1)
     rst.Close
     For i = LBound(TimeArray) To UBound(TimeArray)
     Next i


Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strsql)
Count = 0
     ReDim Preserve CommentArray(0)
     rst.MoveFirst
     Do Until rst.EOF
        CommentArray(Count) = rst![Comment]

        ReDim Preserve CommentArray(UBound(CommentArray) + 1)
        Count = Count + 1
        rst.MoveNext
     Loop

     ReDim Preserve CommentArray(UBound(CommentArray) - 1)
     rst.Close
     For i = LBound(CommentArray) To UBound(CommentArray)
     TimeCommentArray = TimeArray(i) & " - " & CommentArray(i)

     Debug.Print TimeCommentArray
     Next i


     End Sub
```

When I run my

```
Debug.Print TimeCommentArray
```

it's in the Immediate window exactly how I need it but I cant figure out how to pull it into the .Body of an Outlook email.  It only captures and sends over the last line (i.e. last comment) of the concatenated arrays.

My email creation code is in this same sub... after the above code that I'm using to create my arrays.

Any help/suggestions would be very much appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeCommentArray = TimeCommentArray & vbcrlf & TimeArray(i) & _
                                    " - " & CommentArray(i)
```